# Printer sharing and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, sharing, printing, networking

I have a printer plugged it into my Ubuntu desktop machine. I want to access it from Windows 7 on my laptop. Is this possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup. Quite simple too. IMO this is quicker than using cups' web gui.

1. Make cups accept connections from other computers.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
   ```

   And then replace `Listen localhost:631` with `Listen *:631`. Save and exit (control+x, y, return).

   Note: If this computer ever goes out into the wild, where it's not hidden behind a router, it might be worth specifying an IP address instead of wildcarding. If it sits behind a protected router all the time, you don't need to worry about it.

   Note 2: If you have a firewall running on your computer (eg ufw, firestarter) be sure to allow connections on port 631 through.
2. Restart cups:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/cupsys restart
   ```
3. From the Windows computer, start the Add a printer wizard (in Control Panel > Printers), select network printer and when you finally get around to the part where you enter an address, stick something like this in:

   ```
   http://your_ubuntu_ip:631/printers/whatever_your_printer_is_called
   ```

   You then just install the Windows drivers for it and bish, bash, bong your're done.

   If you don't know the name (to replace `whatever_your_printer_is_called`), take a look at cups http://localhost:631 and see what the name is for the printer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is possible.

Please look at [Network Printing With Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu).